# expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++

```
const int BRICKTYPECOUNT = 7;
const sf::Vector2<int> BRICKSIZE(4,4);
int BRICKSTATES[tetris::BRICKTYPECOUNT][BRICKSIZE.x][8]
{

};
```

Ругается на `BRICKSIZE.x` И `BRICKSIZE.y` почему?

И даже так не работает

```
const int BRICKTYPECOUNT = 7;
const sf::Vector2<const int> BRICKSIZE(4,4);
int BRICKSTATES[tetris::BRICKTYPECOUNT][BRICKSIZE.x][8]
{

};
```

Comment: стандартный с++ не поддерживает массивы переменной длины.

Answer (score 0):

```
int BRICKSTATES[tetris::BRICKTYPECOUNT][BRICKSIZE.x][8]
```

это обьявление памяти в стеке. Есть регистр **%rsp** , который указывает на вершину стека. Данное обьявление выделяет место в стеке так : **%rsp:=%rsp-size**. Вы не можете изменить размер массива, который находиться в стеке, так как он завален другими данными. Выхода два : или в проге нужна константа размера массива, или выделяем память динамически с помощью **new**.